# MacOS Sonoma: HTTP(S) blocked for one specific user

Tags: networking, macos

I am trying to find the cause for outgoing HTTP(s) traffic being blocked for one specific user on a MacbookPro M1 running MacOS 14.2.

Outgoing connections to ports 80 and 443 get blocked with "connection refused" for *just this one user*:

```
macbookpro14:~ user1$ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.185.110): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.250.185.110: icmp_seq=0 ttl=60 time=9.462 ms
^C
macbookpro14:~ user1$ nc -v imap.googlemail.com 993
Connection to imap.googlemail.com port 993 [tcp/imaps] succeeded!
^C
macbookpro14:~ user1$ nc -v google.com 443
nc: connectx to google.com port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
nc: connectx to google.com port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
macbookpro14:~ user1$ su - user2
Password:

user2@macbookpro14: ~ $ ping google.com                                                                                                                                                                    PING google.com (142.250.186.174): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.250.186.174: icmp_seq=0 ttl=60 time=19.515 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 19.515/19.515/19.515/0.000 ms

user2@macbookpro14: ~ $ nc -v google.com 443                                                                                                                                                               
Connection to google.com port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!
^C
```

I have no ideas anymore what I should be looking for, firewall is off, everything but port 443 and port 80 seems to work, but these do not even work inside my local network. If I login as a different user these ports also work, so I am scratching any router issues of the list.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm seeing something broadly similar on an M3 running 14.3.

Comment: Nope, but the issue mostly just disappeared, haven't had the problem in a while now.